Can I use lagged independent variable as an instrument?
I am doing my Economics dissertation on the impact of competition law stringency (measured 0 to 1 on an index) on R&D levels as a % of GDP. I have an unbalanced panel data set of countries from 1981- 2010. I am using a country- year fixed effects approach to account for any time- invariant country characteristics or time specific characteristics which don't vary by country. I am using the competition law index with 1 year lag.
However there of course could still be some omitted variable bias, so I intend on using an IV. I have considered a few options for this IV (based on available data), such as the budget allocated to each competition law regulator each year as a % of GDP, or the number of staff employed by each country's regulator each year. However I am unsure if these could meet the exclusion restriction.
I have found a similar paper which made use of "Internal instruments" which used lagged a independent variable as an instrument.
(https://repositorio.redinvestigadore...=1&isAllowed=y). I didn't even know this was possible.
Both the budget as a % of GDP and the 5 period lag of the competition law index are valid in the first stage for me, however I am worried that they may not meet the exclusion restriction.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Do it .. see if the estimates make sense. In my experience which is from electricity demand modeling lagged dependent variables do not work as an instrument so I wouldn't expect it to actually work. However you should always aim to apply relevant methods and compare results, that can only strengthen your dissertation.

Thanks for the response! However I am talking about lagging my independent variable, not my dependent variable. e.g. If I used the level of competition law stringency 6 years ago as an instrument for the level of competition law stringency today. The exogeneity assumption would require that stringency 6 years ago has no effect on the error term of R&D as a % of GDP.

You could also use the lagged variable as your X directly

What would this achieve?
